# RestTemplate in Java - Not enough variable values available with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url, resttemplate

I've got the following:

```
final String notification = "{\"DATA\"}";
final String url = "http://{DATA}/create";
ResponseEntity<String> auth = create(address, name, psswd, url);
```

Attacking this method:

```
private ResponseEntity<String> create(final String address, final String name,
                                                          final String newPassword, final String url) {
        final Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
        param.put("name", name);
        param.put("password", newPassword);
        param.put("email", address);

        final HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();

        final HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(param, header);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        return restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, String.class);
    }
```

I think it should work, but it's throwing me a

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'notification'
```

Why?

Comment: @ESala Have you read the first line? You should read the question body and not only the title

Comment: @ESala Indeed, it's a duplicate so I am going to delete the question.

Comment: FYI for future readers: the OP un-accepted the correct answer.

Comment: FYI for future readers: I mistakenly accepted @ESala NON-CORRECT answer. My answer worked.

Comment: @ESala The real answer is the one I've just written

Comment: Can you explain what you are expecting or trying to do with `notification` and `data`?

Answer (score 5):

As the duplicates of your question say, you have `{ }` in your URL.

Spring will try to fill that `{notification}` but since you don't provide it, it fails saying `Not enough variable values available to expand 'notification'`.

You just need to pass the notification string so that Spring can build the URL correctly.

Here is the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) for this method:

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> postForEntity(String url,
                                           Object request,
                                           Class<T> responseType,
                                           Object... uriVariables)
                                    throws RestClientException
Parameters:
    url - the URL
    request - the Object to be POSTed, may be null
    responseType - the class of the response
    uriVariables - the variables to expand the template
```

So, you need to pass the notification string as a 4th parameter, like this:

```
restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, String.class, notification);
```

Answer (score -1):

The following line was just enough to get it working. I got rid of the key characters and it's working now.

```
final String url = "http://DATA/create";
```